# Click, Toggle, Jquery

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

```
var flip = 0;  
     $("#aabbcc").click(function () {  
         $("#navigation_menu_1").toggle( flip++ % 2 == 0 );  
});

<div id="aabbcc"></div> 
  <div id="navigation_menu_1">
<ul>
  <a href="#"><li>Navigation Item</li></a>
</ul>
```

I'm using this small script for a "click menu" 
What I am trying to accomplish is for the active menu which was called upon by one of the buttons to dispay:none if the mouse leaves the div area which was called upon by one of the buttons.

So basically I would click the menu button, a div appears, but if i click anywhere out of the div the menu will go back to displaying as none.

This seems simple but I have been at for hours.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to register a `click()` on the document.  If the `event.target.id` does not equal some constraint simply hide the navigation.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var a = $(event.target).andSelf().parents("#navigation_menu_1");
    if (a.length == 0 && $("#navigation_menu_1").is(":visible")) {
        $("#navigation_menu_1").toggle();
    }
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/uCmex/2/).**

Also, the `flip` variable is not needed, you can just call `.toggle()` directly.

Comment: @Mark- I want to limit which ID Can call the #navigation_menu_1 to toggle is that possible?

Comment: @RPM see the updated fiddle.  I think that is what you are looking for, allows the navigation to be shown and hidden if the menu is clicked off.  But allows for items that are inside of the navigation to be clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

Whoa, why the counter?

Why not just:

```
 $("#aabbcc").click(function () {
     $("#navigation_menu_1").show();
});
```

Also, **you're not handling clicks outside the div** at all.  So **it (should) never disappear**.  This might be a little slow (needs improvement), but it should work for hiding it again:

```
$(div).not("#aabbcc").click(function () {
     $("#navigation_menu_1").hide();
});
```

Again, selecting every div and binding a click event is a bad idea, and I think there might be something along the lines of "Bind to clicks anywhere not on this object," but you get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to display:none on a click outside of the div or a mouseover / mouseout event? If you are looking to hide when it registers a mouse click outside of the div use this:

```
jQuery(document).one("click", function() { jQuery("#navigation_menu_1").fadeOut(); });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/mU89N/

Comment: Awesome, yes this is what I had in mind but I want to call the appearance of the div from a separate unique div So when you click on the unique div the hidden div will show and if you click anywhere out of the hidden div it will 'dissapear'